# regex lookahead assertion does not work

Tags: c#, regex

I want to parse a piece of javascript in C#.

the javascript is like

```
var info1 = {timestamp: "1390678800000",amount: "123",guaranteed: "False"};
var info2 = {timestamp: "1390510500000",amount: "234",guaranteed: "True"};
var info3 = {timestamp: "1390678800000",amount: "123",guaranteed: "False"};
```

what I want is a regex that would extract amount from info2.

I have this regex

```
(?<=(info2((\s|=)+){.+amount:\s?")).*(?=",.*)
```

but instead of 234 it returns

```
234",guaranteed: "True"};var info3 = {timestamp: "1390510500000",amount: "345
```

how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just parse the JSON instead? `{` is a metacharacter btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have a greedy match before your lookahead. Add a `?` to make sure the `.*` consumes as little as possible. I also escaped the `{`.

```regex
(?<=(info2((\s|=)+)\{.+amount:\s?")).*?(?=",.*)
```

Though you probably have `RegexOptions.Singleline` because it should work anyway (unless all your `info`s are on the same line in the actual code?).

If possible, I would suggest using a JSON parser though instead of using a regex.